# teclado se sobrepone encima de los componentes de la actividad

Tags: android

tengo una actividad que es un formulario de registro que ocupa toda la pantalla(fullscrean)

[image: activity_form_registro]

pero cuando aparece el teclado tapa los componentes que estan al ultimo

[image: activity_form_registro]

les puse un scrollview a mis actividades pero tampoco logro que los componentes se dislizen hacia arriba cuando aparece el teclado y también les juro que en el manifest ya probé con todos los atributos del *windowSoftInputMode* y no me funciona con ninguno:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="probe con todos los atributos"
```

al scrollview tambien probe colocandole el atributo de:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

y tampoco funciona, a menos que este haciendo una mala combinación de contenedores, pero alguien que me ayude por favor.

Estas son mis actividades:

activity_form_registro.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FormulariosdeRegistro.FormRegistro">

<include layout="@layout/form_registro"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_forward_white_24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

form_registro.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_form_registro">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPrimerNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="20">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPrimerNombre"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Primer Nombre *"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutSegundoNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="20">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextSegundoNombre"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Segundo Nombre"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutApellidoPaterno"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="20">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextApellidoPaterno"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Apellido Paterno"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutApellidoMaterno"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="20">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextApellidoMaterno"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Apellido Materno"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: si, lo acabo de probar y nada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre de buenas a primeras es capturar el evento onCLick de los componentes editText y, en tiempo de ejecucion, desplazar toda la vista que incluyes hacia arriba.

La ScrollView solo permite el desplazamiento cuando el layout que contiene excede las dimensiones del contenedor padre. El teclado no forma parte de la activity que visualizas, por eso aunque parezca que hay demasiados elementos en pantalla no se activa la funcionalidad del ScrollView.

Comment: buen punto, lo voy a considerar pero veo otros casos que tienen el mismo problema que yo y lo solucionan agregando atributos en el Manifest, pero no se porque a mi no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo el layout esta bien armado, existe una forma muy limpia de solucionar este problema sin tener que tocar mucho el layout

Primero vamos a setear en el Manifest `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` esto hara que el contenedor(el windows) del activity se ajuste dejando lugar para el teclado.

Dentro del manifest tenes que poner esto:

```
<activity
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
   .../>
```

Por lo que decis esto ya lo intentaste y no te resulto, eso se debe a que te esta faltando un ultimo detalle y es el `fitsSystemWindows` en el layout del Activity. Esto hara que al cambiar el tamaño del Windows tu Activity se ajuste a ese nuevo tamaño.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   tools:context=".FormulariosdeRegistro.FormRegistro">
```

Con esto deberia bastar para que la pantalla se recorte al aparecer el teclado. Pero recuerda que es indispensable que tengas un buen scroll puesto para no tener problemas.

Hay otras formas de resolver el problema sin tener que recortar la pantalla, aveces puede resultar agregarle espacio vacio al ScrollView para que puedas acceder a lo que esta debajo del teclado. Pero eso solo te lo recomendaria en casos muy particulares del diseño.

Comment: nada, no funciona.